# @Transformer for ObjectToJson Not Working in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

A POJO Message.java is to be Converted to JSON(JSON is to be sent to pubsub Topic,using Spring Integration MessageChannels.),using following:

```
@Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel", outputChannel = "handleOutChannel")
    public ObjectToJsonTransformer transformOut() {

        return new ObjectToJsonTransformer();
    }


    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
      public interface PubsubOutboundGateway {

        void sendToPubsub(Messages msg);
      }

    @Bean
      @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "handleOutChannel")
      public MessageHandler messageSender(PubSubOperations pubsubTemplate) {
        return new PubSubMessageHandler(pubsubTemplate, "TestTopic");
      }
```

When i call sendToPubsub() with an instance of Message.java with required properties set,i get an error "Null".

Is serviceActivator not able to receive the required data?
Any suggestions to fix this?.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can't do that because you just don't tell it to do that.

Your gateway is configured for this:

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "handleOutChannel")
```

But that is not an input channel for the `ObjectToJsonTransformer`. So, whatever you send over that gateway is going directly to the `messageSender` service activator.

Try to configure your gateway like this:

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
```

Comment: Please, don’t show code and stack traces in comments. As you see it’s not readable. Edit your question with more info. Anyway doesn’t look like related to what we have with Integration configuration above.

Comment: thanks for pointing out ,i have updated the code...can you please suggest how to fix the issue,as now i am  getting "NULL" while hitting the Controller with required inputs.

Comment: Show stack trace in that case